# special characters in mysql?

Tags: mysql

When I created a mysql database, I named it using a hyphen, like `aaron-kyle`.

When I check the database, I see:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| respect-joomla     |
+--------------------+
```

But I can't delete the database.

The specific command I used was:

```
mysql> drop database respect-joomla;
```

The error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '-joomla' at line 1
```

I also tried:

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE 'respect-joomla';
```

I get the same error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near ''respect-joomla'' at line 1
```

Are there special ways to write - in mysql (like space in the command line is \ \ ) ?

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the command you tried to use? You have a syntax error but right now we can only guess why.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, John!  I have updated the question.  Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DROP DATABASE `aaron-kyle`;
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for this suggestion.  I had tried with the ', but it also didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Read more carefully what I posted in the answer. You should use ` not '.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  Too new to appreciate that there was a difference.  Using the back tick worked!